# Sandbox Solution: How to use resource files in master page

Tags: master-page, sandbox-solution, resource-files

When i create a sandbox solution, and i want to use resources in my code, i use sattelite assemblies.

But in my masterpage it seems not to work, i get following error:

```
Parser Error Message: The resource object with key 'sps_contactus_link' was not found.
```

---

If i use

```
NavigateURL="<% $Resources:Resources.Properties, sps_sitemap_focusareas_link %>"
```

then i get the following error:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resources.Resources.Properties.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

But if i use

```
NavigateURL="<% $Resources:Properties, sps_sitemap_focusareas_link %>"
```

then i get the following error:

```
The resource object with key 'sps_sitemap_focusareas_link' was not found.
```

Comment: Do an IIsreset and the values will get reflected

Answer (score 1):

are you using embedded resources and accessing them in Sandbox solution likely?

See more details: http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2011/03/localization-in-sharepoint-2010-sandbox.html

Comment: I work like that way, and that works fine in my C# code; but when I want to use it in a master page I get the error.